# Is there a table to query for Oracle Reserved Words?

Tags: oracle

Is there a table i can query all of Oracle Reserved Words?

Example, i can query `user_tab_cols` or `all_tab_cols` for handy to-date table information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a view called [v$reserved_words](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/dynviews_2048.htm#REFRN30204)

Comment: Thanks. "ORA-00942: table or view does not exist" Am i missing rights?